# How can I return the longest string in an array—even if the array contains items that are not strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

Let's say I'm writing a function like so:

```
function longestString (someArray) {
    // code
}
```

If `someArray = ['word','longer phrase',['a','b','c'],1234567891011121314151617]`, I would want the function to only return the longest **string** in the array and ignore the integers and other arrays that may also lie within it. I tried this:

```
function longestString (someArray) {
    return someArray.sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })[0];
}
```

It didn't work, and I am now stuck. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter only string element and do it

```
function longestString (someArray) {
    return someArray
        .filter(function(a){ return typeof(a)=='string' })
        .sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function longestString(someArray) {
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
        if ((typeof someArray[i] === "string") && (someArray[i].length > result.length)) {
            result = someArray[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do :

```
function longestString (someArray) {
$longest_string = '';
foreach ($someArray as $value)
    {
     $current_length = strlen($longest_string);
     if(strlen($value) > $current_length )  $longest_string = $value;
    }

    return $longest_string;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var a = ['word', 'longer phrase', ['a', 'b', 'c'], 1234567891011121314151617];

returnLongestString(a);

function returnLongestString(arr) {
 var longestString = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (typeof arr[i] == "string" && arr[i].length > longestString.length) {
   longestString = arr[i];
  }
    };
 return longestString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I saw this question, it had 0 answers, when I finished writing and testing my function, there were five. But this is my approach:

The key here is to first filter only the strings. Then, list all the lengths on an array. Then using that array you can get a match on the bigger one.

```
function longestString (someArray) {
//we only need strings, so first we will filter all the data
var stringsOnly = [];
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    if(typeof(someArray[i]) === 'string'){
        stringsOnly.push(someArray[i]);
    }
};
//Now with an array of just strings, we can get their indivial lenghts
var stringLengths = [];
for (var i = 0; i < stringsOnly.length; i++) {
    var currentString = stringsOnly[i];
    stringLengths.push(currentString.length);
};
//Get the max length
var maxLength = Math.max.apply(Math,stringLengths);
//get a string wich length equals to maxLength
for (var i = 0; i < stringsOnly.length; i++) {
    var theString = stringsOnly[i];
    if(theString.length === maxLength){return theString};
 }; 
}
```

This function will return the largest string. If more than one string have the same length, It will return the first one. However, if you want to get various strings, you could make some little modificationson the function above:

```
function multipleLongestString (someArray) {
//we only need strings, so first we will filter all the data
var stringsOnly = [];
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    if(typeof(someArray[i]) === 'string'){
        stringsOnly.push(someArray[i]);
    }
};
//Now with an array of just strings, we can get their indivial lenghts
var stringLengths = [];
for (var i = 0; i < stringsOnly.length; i++) {
    var currentString = stringsOnly[i];
    stringLengths.push(currentString.length);
};
//Get the max length
var maxLength = Math.max.apply(Math,stringLengths);

//modification here
longests = [];
//get a string wich length equals to maxLength
for (var i = 0; i < stringsOnly.length; i++) {
    var theString = stringsOnly[i];
    if(theString.length === maxLength){longests.push(theString)};
 };
return longests;
}
```

That is an extra that may help you later. But if you just want the largest one, use the first function. I hope that my answer is relevant.

:)

Answer (score -1):

Heres my approach at it.  Really all you want to know is if the phrase is longer than the previous and if its a string.

[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/m0jLajdz/)

```
var someArray = ['word','longer phrase',['a','b','c'],1234567891011121314151617]

var longestString = function(arr) {
    var longest = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var value = arr[i];
        if (typeof value === "string") {
            longest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    alert(longest);
}

longestString(someArray);
```